# Match on site root, with snap webframework

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I'm building a site with Snap.

In my routes, how do I match on the site's root directory?

i.e.

```
routes = [(ByteString, Handler App App ())]
routes = [("/", redirect "www.google.com")]
```

The above code doesn't redirect when called at(localhost:8000/).

Comment: Try replacing "/" with "" - does that fix it? Also, see the ifTop combinator for matching *only* the site root.

Comment: `wrapSite (\site -> ifTop (redirect "http://www.google.com") <|> site)`

Comment: Ok thanks. But why doesnt "/" work

Comment: See @Rodrigo Taboada 's answer, you missed the http://

Comment: @MdxBhmt when I do ("/", render "about")  it doesnt work either.

Comment: @dave It's because "/" will match to "/". You have to call localhost:8000//

Comment: @MdxBhmt, if that were true, that would mean "/about" would match to "/about", but it matches to "localhost:8000/about"... So it still doesn't make sense

Comment: Yeah, there is something weird going on. "//about" does match like  "/about".
I guess there must be something overrulling the route for "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "http://" to the URI. This works in my machine:

```
routes = [("/", redirect "http://www.google.com")]
```

You can also use `ifTop`:

```
site :: Snap ()
site = ifTop (redirect "http://www.google.com) <|>
       route routes
```

Where `routes` contains the remaining routes of your site.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a template called `index.tpl`, then the `"/"` handler will never get called. I found this out through trial and error.

Comment: Wow, good to know! Thank you. I definitely have that. You should submit a bug report. https://github.com/snapframework/snap/issues

Comment: I think this is considered a feature :-) Apparently the Heist snaplet grabs this route if index.tpl is present. Even stranger to me is that the "/" handler matches everything, like the "" handler, so you need to use ifTop with it. Not sure if that is a feature, too...

Comment: I discovered this the hard way too, but if you move where you declare your routes then this works better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597971/snap-framework-root-route-not-being-handed

Comment: See this for more info:
Adding a route for "": https://github.com/snapframework/snap/blob/dc00f47b60b4502677bb60fe588ea0d342801a55/src/Snap/Snaplet/Heist/Internal.hs#L52
What that route actually serves: https://github.com/snapframework/snap/blob/dc00f47b60b4502677bb60fe588ea0d342801a55/src/Snap/Snaplet/HeistNoClass.hs#L337