# Snap framework root ("/") route not being handed?

Tags: haskell, routes, haskell-snap-framework

I have added routes to my app in the following format:

```
addRoutes 
  [ ("/",     redirect "/docs/home")
  , ... more routes
  ]
```

But for some reason the root handler is being ignored altogether. What is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that if you have an index.tpl file then the SnapFramework will ignore any "/" mappings and go straight to that instead. To fix the problem I just ran:

```
git rm snaplets/heist/templates/index.tpl
```

And then reloaded my templates and the route on root started working.

(I could not find that anywhere in the docs so I decided to post that here)

Edit: [I later discovered](https://github.com/snapframework/snap-core/issues/216#issuecomment-60709584) (with help) that the problem was that I was adding my routes AFTER I ran heistInit. If i added my routes before heistInit then there was no problem.

Comment: It depends on precisely how you've set up all your routes.  I'd need to see all your code to tell you more.  Most likely there was a heistServe route before your "/" route.

Comment: Luckily, I'm writing a public Atlassian Connect application so you can see my routes code here: https://bitbucket.org/eerok/ping-me-connect/src/2b339e46c962d2b96267af7d8721944f705d2372/src/Site.hs?at=master#cl-102